# Django クラスTemplateViewを使った処理でif文を関数に

Tags: python, django

Python歴一か月

仮に

ToDoリストのタスク完了画面を想定
ブラウザの一つの画面から３つのボタンが用意されてる。
ボタン３つ処理が異なる。
　１つめのボタン
　　選択された完了タスクをToDoリストに戻す。
　２つめのボタン
　　選択された完了タスクをDB上から削除。
　３つめのボタン
　　完了タスクをすべてDBから削除
現在のコード

```
class task_end(TemplateView):
""" タスク完了画面"""
def get(self,request):
   省略


def post(self, request):
    """各POSTからのボタンに対する処理"""

    # 完了したタスクを ToDoリストに戻す
    if 'task_in' in request.POST:
        tasks = task.objects.get(id=request.POST['id'])
        tasks.status = False
        tasks.save()

    # 完了したタスクを1件をDBから削除
    elif 'task_delete' in request.POST:
        tasks = task.objects.get(id=request.POST['id'])
        tasks.delete()

    # 完了したタスクのリスト全てを削除
    elif 'task_all_delete' in request.POST:
        tasks = task.objects.all().filter(users=request.session['u_s_id'], status=True)
        tasks.delete()

    return redirect('task_end')
```

この場合ブラウザからのPOST処理に対して、if文で処理を分岐しています。
実際ブラックボックスで動かすと問題はないのですが、本当にこのような分岐方法でいいのか？

他に間違いなくいい方法があると思います。
もしよろしければアドバイス等よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 少なくとも2つめ以降の`if` は `else if` の方が適切な気がします。

Comment: それ以外に何か方法はありますか？

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/155787